# Антивирус для Linux x64

Tags: joomla, linux

Добрый день! Я использую LinuxMint 12 (lisa) x64, для администрирования своего сайта на Joomla 1.5.23 и доступа по FTP. **Вопрос**: чтобы не занести заразу, надо ли мне ставить, дополнительно, еще и антивирус для Linux (они сейчас появляются разные) и если да то какой?

Answer (score 1):

На вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные... )Вопросы безопасности хостинга антивирус не решит. Для файлопомойки, где хранится и виндовс софт, я использую ClamAV или Avast

Comment: Спасибо! Но все же - возможно ли занести на сайт вирус (троян, spyware и т.д.) работая из Linux по FTP ?? И поможет ли в этом антивирус для Линукс ( кстати нигде не нашел антивирус под Linux x64 ? )?

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное - не нарушать правил инфобезопасности (не работать под рутом, и т.п.). А антивирус можно использовать любой - глобальных различий в них нет. Другое дело, что Clam бесплатен и имеется во всех репозитариях. Сам ресурс можно проверять Clam`ом подключив его в виде vfs, тогда антивирь воспринимает его как локальную папку в хоуме.Насчет ftp: лучше использовать sftp - все линуховые ftp-клиенты это умеют... 
Вирус через ftp занесется только в том случае, если заражена система с которой сливают инфу.

Answer (score 1):

Шесть пять и ни одного всецело верного, куда катится сообщество?

На настоящий момент антивирусы в GNU/Linux нужны для поиска win-вирусах в файлах предназначенных для windows пользователей (например для проверки электронной почты проходящей через сервер). Антивирус в GNU/Linux это не средство личной безопасности, насущная необходимость, а инструмент для поиска вирусов в файлах. В некоторых (по моим наблюдениям достаточно редких) случаях такой инструмент бывает действительно необходим, так-же как в некоторых случаях бывает необходим скальпель или токарный станок, но у большинства людей за всю жизнь так ни разу и не возникнет реальной потребности  подобных вещах.

Следует понимать что то что сейчас в windows называется антивирусом имеет не так уж много общего с тем что называлось антивирусом изначально. Это программные комплексы обвешанные разномастным функционалом должным (по задумке авторов, или маркетологов) защитить пользователя от всех мыслимых опасностей, от рекламных баннеров на сайтов, до нехороших сайтов в интернете, могущих повредить детскую психику.

Те-же антивирусы о которых говорят в контексте GNU/Linux это примерно то-же самое что подразумевалось под антивирусами изначально (в контексте вычислительной техники, разумеется). Это программы для поиска в файлах вредоносного кода. У них просто не было причин идти по пути по которому пошли их win-собратья. Фактически удобнее думать о win- и lin-антивирусах как о разных сущностях.

Многие начинающие линуксоиды, по старой виндовой привычке, первым делам установив на свой компьютер дистрибутив GNU/Linux пытаются поставить антивирус. Как правило всё заканчивается вопросом на форуме и установкой ClamAV (который впоследствии лежит на жёстком диске мёртвым грузом). Я и сам в своё время прошёл этим путём.

Часто можно слышать весьма категоричные высказывания в том смысле что «под линух вирусов нет», или ироничные вроде «вирусы есть, но что-бы заставить их работать на своём компе нужно попотеть».

В некотором приближении такие высказывания действительно верны. И этого приближения вполне достаточно для [@Slon_XXL](/users/839/slon_xxl) и всех прочих новичков в GNU/Linux задающихся такими вопросами.

Более точный ответ потребовал-бы основательно углубиться в теорию и для начала ответить на вопросы вроде «что такое вирус» и «что такое Linux» (ответы на эти вопросы не так уж однозначны, во всяком случае если не подходить к ним формально). Всё это явно далеко выходит за рамки этого ответа, и без того пространного сверх всякой меры.

Резюмирую: новичку приходящему в мир Unix (GNU/Linux — частный случай) будет разумно оставить свои старые windows-страхи, дабы освободить в уме место для новых страхов (:

Answer (score 0):

Как так, не найти антивирус под Linux x64, если стандартный для никсов ClamAV существует в двух вариантах. Причем доступен в стандартных репах практически любого дистрибутива.Как максимум защиты, можно использовать Kaspersky Endpoint Security.

Answer (score 0):

А антивирус можно использовать любой - глобальных различий в них нет.

Да, но самый лучший это Kaspersky и dr.web.